# UI-select placeholder disappears after select

Tags: ui-select

I'm trying to use ui-select to make a state selection but when I select a 
state the placeholder goes blank, does anyone know how to not make 
"Filter by province/state" disappear.

[image: before selecting]

[image: after...]

Here is the code for ui-select-match section of my ui-select:

```
                        <ui-select-match
                            placeholder="Filter by province/state">
                            {/ $item /}
                        </ui-select-match>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use a separate label because ui-select usually has the saved array inside of the input box which is why the display label disappears once their is one item in the array.